# I am expecting myApp.exe runs faster than myApp.vshost.exe, but

Tags: c#, performance

from vshost  (run in VS release)

```
 array pure 00:00:02.9634819
 1200000000
 Basic: 00:00:04.1682663
```

from standalone program (compiled release)

```
 array pure 00:00:09.1783278 // slower, why?
 1200000000
 Basic: 00:00:00.5985118  // faster, as expected
```

So it seems that running from VS sometimes speed up the programs?

My test code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace vsHostTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static long Five(int s0, int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4)
        {
            return s4 + 100 * s3 + 10000 * s2 + 1000000 * s1 + 100000000 * s0;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            long testSize = 10000000;
            int[] myarray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
            watch.Start();
            for (int j = 0; j < testSize; j++)
            {

                bool i = myarray.Contains(2);

            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("array pure {0}", watch.Elapsed);

            testSize = 200000000;
            long checksum = 0;
            watch.Restart();
            for (long i = 0; i < testSize; i++)
            {
                long ret = Five(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
                checksum += ret % 9;
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(checksum);
            Console.WriteLine("Basic: {0}", watch.Elapsed);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Improper micro-benchmark detected: no warm-up, single in-process run.

Comment: @pst that's 9 sec run, or u have better idea? I have a bigger app which behaves differently in vshost and standalone, so I tried to breakdown into small pieces. This is the place which attracts my attention

Comment: See above. Improper micro-benchmark. Give the VM time to warm-up. The easiest way to do this is just to run all the tests a number of times in a big loop (make sure to use Restart or a new watch *all* the time) -- still not ideal but it has a better chance of revealing the outliers.

Comment: You'll need to document that you are running this code on a 64-bit operating system.  With the first result probably obtained in 32-bit mode.

Comment: @HansPassant I compiled and ran both in x86 version

Comment: Hmm, well, do you run this on a 64-bit operating system?  That's what your results say.

Comment: @HansPassant yes, how do u derive that? Does that have impact on the performance?

Comment: @HansPassant I then compiled in x64, it turned out the standalone app run faster than the x86 peer, could u elaborate a bit more in an answer post? I will mark it as the proper answer afterwards. thx

Comment: The kind of measurement you got from "basic" can only be produced by the aggressive inlining and expression optimization done by the x64 jitter.  You were comparing apples and oranges.

Answer (score 3):

I ran each one four times, but not including the first result for each average.

> vshost:
>
> array pure: 6.83   Basic: 3.62
>
> console:
>
> array pure: 6.64  Basic: 1.57

I should add that all times were slower in vshost than they were in console.  I'm not sure why you're getting the results you are, but vshost attaches a debugger to the process whereas running it via console does not.  The console version will always be faster because of that.

Furthermore, while benchmarking .net applications, running the test once is not enough to get accurate measurements.  You should always run the test multiple numbers of times, throwing out either the first (if you want don't want to compare cold runs, as .net caches a lot) or the most outlying measurement.

Also, and I feel stupid for asking this, are you sure you ran the release version when you were running via console?  I'm sure you did, but I always ask, since I sometimes make silly mistakes like that.

Comment: thx for ur testing, now i am convinced that it is the x64 thing that messed up.